# Use shortcuts with key strokes on secondary level

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Sometimes I see pre-defined shortcuts in macOS where one part of them are using the second level of keys, e.g. stroke "/" of the key <kbd>7</kbd>. As everybody knows, at least this secondary level can be accessed by the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.

Well, coming from this pattern, I was a bit confused about such kind of pre-defined shortcuts: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. My initial assumption to utilize these kind of shortcut was to use modifiers like this <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>, which wasn't working well unfortunately.

My assumption is that I have a fundamental misunderstanding in using secondary key strokes in shortcuts. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: Where exactly did you run into this issue, and with which keyboard layout? I justed tested Cmd-+ in Safari, had to type Cmd-Shift-1 on the Swiss keyboard to get the page to zoom as expected (Cmd-1 switches to the first tab).

Comment: I have seen this in Xcode. The keyboard I have is German. So you mean it could be reasoned by keyboard layout differences that are not considered in the pre-defined shortcut definitions?

Comment: I just tested it here: To trigger "Toggle Comments" I need to press Cmd-Shift-7 (as `/` is Shift-7) as expected. Do you have some other software running which captures keystrokes?

Comment: Hm, interesting. Honestly, I don't know what other software is capturing exactly that keystroke (already exited all other obviously open or running software), but if it working for you, it might be an issue with Xcode itself (overlapping pre-defined shortcuts that block themselves)...